# Best type of field in Jira for handling job codes?

Tags: jira

We essentially have a centralized project, but bits and pieces of that project are built with funding from many different budgets. Separate billing codes are created for each budget.

I want to place a field on all of our issues that stores the job code that should have that issues logged hours be billed against. **What type of field do you think is best suited for this?**

FWIW, I currently have a regular text field, but this is tedious for PMs to consistently enter codes into and I've had multiple folks ask me to replace the field with something more intuitive and user friendly. Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend on the job code structure and hierarchy (if applicable).

We added a custom field: select list (cascading) type with all our account codes within by department.

It's "selectable" and allows to seek and filter. Nevertheless, if they are many this is gonna be messy.

Maybe you can add a parent level by Job Source, Department, Company, Vendor, etc... to filter your job codes later.

Look at this tutorial on YouTube.
[Example Configure Cascade List In Jira Cloud](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K-yG7mJfyUQ)

---

Another suggestion. If your projects are internal and as you use JIRA, I have an intuition that you are going in an agile approach maybe. It means that you are involving your stakeholders in the projects of the company to fulfill their expectations (sprint initiation, review and retrospective). You can create an access to key stakehokders per project and allow them to specify some data for your user stories (job codes) and later confirm the resolution of the issues after quality control. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and guidance, Maximus.

Comment: @LesterPeabody Sure no problem. I edited my answer to add another suggestions that can help your Project Managers. Good luck.